How to temporarily disable system versioning with HsqlDB
On a HsqlDB 2.7.3 database I use tables with system versioning.
I would like to know if it is possible to deactivate system versioning temporarily and more precisely for the duration of an update, a delete or an insert.
Thanks.

The system is not designed to do this.
If this was possible, you could have a situation where a new row is inserted without versioning, with a foreign key referencing a row that was under system versioning. The database could become rather incoherent as far as time travel queries are concerned.
